# How to draw an equilateral triangle in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to create a equilateral triangle with JavaFX. It is said that use the Polygon and `setLayoutX()` and `setLayoutY()`. So how to do that?  This is the code I tried:

```
@Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Board");
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 519);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying? I see no code posted here.

Comment: Sorry, just a tiny project.
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Board");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 519);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
        stage.show();

    }
I'm stuck in Polygon triangle part, don't know what to do next.

Comment: Next time, just edit the post. Don't add the code in the comments.

Comment: Carter, this my answer helped at all? It's been almost a day with no feedback from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You did not add the polygon to the container
2. You did not define the points of the polygon

Your code should be something like this:

```
@Override
public void start (Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Board");
    Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
    //triangle.setLayoutX(100);
    //triangle.setLayoutY(400);
    triangle.getPoints()
        .addAll(new Double[] {300.0, 50.0, 250.0, 100.0, 350.0, 100.0,});
    Group root = new Group(triangle); // You can replace with StackPane for center alignment
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 519);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Once you do that, you should see something like the image below. You need to figure out the (x,y) coordinates for your triangle.

[image]

When I uncommented the `setLayoutX()` and `setLayoutY()` lines, the result was like the image below.

[image]

If you need a drawing in Java FX tutorial, check out [this](https://edencoding.com/3-ways-to-draw-triangles-in-javafx-all-with-free-code/) site.

Comment: Could you tell me what's "new Double[] {300.0, 50.0, 250.0, 100.0, 350.0, 100.0,}" means?

Comment: @CarterZhang that's the array of the `(x, y)` coordinates of the vertices.